Check MLE estimator is asymptotically normal
Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. random variables, with parameter $\theta > 0$, such that:
$$X_i \sim \mathrm B\left(\frac{1}{\theta}, 1\right)$$ with PDF:
$$f(x,\theta) = \frac{x^\frac{1}{\theta}}{x\theta}\Bbb I_{(0, 1)}$$
Show that MLE of $X_i$ is asymptotically normal, i.e.:
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta\right) \overset{D}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal N\left(0, \mathrm{Var}_\theta X_1\right)$$
Using MLE, I've calculated estimate as: $$\hat{\theta}_n = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log X_i$$
By the central limit theorem, it follows:
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X}_n - \mathsf{E}_\theta X_1\right) = \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - \frac{1}{1 + \theta}\right) \overset{D}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal N\left(0, \mathrm{Var}_\theta X_1\right) = \mathcal N\left(0, \frac{1}{2\theta + 1} - \frac{1}{(1 + \theta)^2}\right)$$
But I have trouble to use the right transformation (either using delta method or continuous mapping theorem to show asymptotic normality of $\hat{\theta}_n$).
Hints are welcome.
Thanks.

In this particular case, you should recognize that if $$X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(1/\theta, 1),$$
then
$$Y = -\log X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 1/\theta),$$
hence
$$\hat \theta_n \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, n/\theta),$$
where the gamma distribution is parametrized by shape and rate.  I leave the proof of these as an exercise.
Finally, we can invoke the CLT, knowing that the exact mean and variance are $\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta_n] = \theta$ and $\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta_n] = \theta^2/n$.

Thanks, but I would like to know how to solve it in general, i.e. specific distribution isn’t that important for this purpose. I have seen example that it could be shown using delta method, continuous transform theorem or Slutsky’s theorem, so I would like to solve it algebraically if possible.

@meerkat Well, the first problem with your approach is that you're not applying the CLT to your estimator.  You're applying it to the sample mean $\bar X$ instead of the log-transformed sample, so you have no connection to the asymptotics of $\hat \theta_n$.  You need to fix this issue first.  Since you asked for hints, I am refraining from providing you a full solution.

Thanks for insight, I think I get what you mean. We have $Y_i$ i.i.d. where $Y_i = -log(X_i)$, so by CLT we get: $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta\right) \overset{D}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal N\left(0, \theta^2\right)$. So at least I got here, although, it's not exactly asymptotically normal as per definition I've got, since $Var X_1$ is: $\frac{1}{2\theta + 1} - \frac{1}{(1 + \theta)^2}$

My bad, you're right. Var is calculated of estimate, so this is correct.
